# Using multiple keys for one value in a Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a Python dictionary that uses integers as keys

```
d[7] = ...
```

to reference custom objects:

```
c = Car()
d[7] = c
```

However, each of these custom objects also has a string identifier (from a third party). I want to be able to access the objects using both an integer or a string. Is the preferred way to use both keys in the same dictionary?

```
d[7] = c
d["uAbdskmakclsa"] = c
```

Or should I split it up into two dictionaries? Or is there a better way?

Comment: I would use 2 dictionaries, I dislike the idea of using multiple ways to index into the same dictionary.

Comment: @JonClements Sorry, I'm used to types...

Comment: @sdasdadas: Python is as strongly typed as C++ or Java or whatever language you're used to. It's just _dynamically_ typed—that is, the _names_ don't have types, only the _values_. (Also, a _good_ statically-typed language could infer the type of `c`, so you still wouldn't need to type it yourself.)

Comment: @abarnert +1 because I always confuse static/dynamic and weak/strong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on what you're doing.

If you get the different kinds of keys from different sources, so you always know which kind you're looking up, it makes more sense, conceptually, to use separate dictionaries.

On the other hand, if you need to be able to handle keys that could be either kind, it's probably simpler to use a single dictionary. Otherwise, you need to write code like that uses type-switching, or tries one dict and then tries the other on `KeyError`, or something else ugly.

(If you're worried about efficiency, it really won't make much difference either way. It's only a very, very tiny bit faster to look things up in a 5000-key dictionary as in a 10000-key dictionary, and it only costs a very small of extra memory to keep two 5000-key dictionaries than one 10000-key dictionary. So, don't worry about efficiency; do whichever makes sense. I don't have any reason to believe you *are* worried about efficiency, but a lot of people who ask questions like this seem to be, so I'm just covering the bases.)

Comment: I like this because I'm finding it a bit of a pain to carry two dictionaries around...

Comment: @sdasdadas: If they're conceptually separate, but you don't want to carry them around separately, you can always wrap to dicts in one object, as sharpcloud suggests. I don't really like `bothdict.byindex(index)` vs. `bothdict.byname(name)` instead of `indexdict[index]` vs. `namedict[name]`… but, as sharpcloud points out, you also get `bothdict.add(index, name, value)` does seem nicer than `indexdict[i]=value; namedict[name]=value`, which _does_ seem like an improvement. So, it's a tradeoff to think about.

Comment: @sdasdadas: Also, you can of course just pass around a tuple of two dicts, and unpack it where you need to use them repeatedly, or just `dicts[0][index]` where you just need a quick one-shot.

Comment: Thanks, I can see how wrapping it into a higher structure might be helpful. I failed to mention that I'm working on the assumption that the data is immutable. In this case, I don't really have a reason for worrying about keeping the two in sync (other than when I first load them into the dictionary). EDIT: Also, the two keys will never collide - I'm sure of that for my example.

Comment: @sdasdadas: I implicitly assumed the keys couldn't collide—in fact, I assumed that the two kinds of keys are of distinguishable types—based on your examples. But it's good to make that assumption explicit.

Answer (score 1):

It's a fairly specific situation, I doubt there is any 'official' preference on what to do in this situation. I do however, feel that having keys of multiple types is 'dirty', although I can't really think of a reason why it is.

But since you state that the string keys come from a third party, that alone might be a good reason to split off to another dictionary. I would split as well. You never know what the future might bring and this method is easier to maintain. Also less error prone if you think of type safety.

For setting values in your dictionaries you can then use helper methods. This will make adding easier and prevent you from forgetting to add/update to one of the dictionaries.

Comment: I'm not sure about the helper method idea. If you really have keys that could be of either kind (and the keys can't collide), there's really no harm in using a single dictionary, and it makes things simpler. Contrarily, if you always know what kind of key you have, you don't want to call the same helper method in both cases, so the helper methods don't add anything.

Comment: You are right about the helper method part. I was thinking more of adding to both dictionaries that would 'require' such a function. Retrieving won't, indeed. In the end there is no definitive choice, but still I wouldn't like mixing types for keys. But I guess that's preference coming from years of programming in type-safe languages. :)

Comment: I think it feels 'dirty' because you might update one of the values and not the other. That's why I'd prefer @perreal's answer since it keeps the objects under a canonical key and uses another dictionary to map other keys to the canonical one.

Comment: That's a good point that the adding-to-both part might be worth wrapping up.

Answer (score 1):

I would use two dicts. One mapping 3rd party keys to integer keys and another one mapping integer keys to objects. Depending on which one you use more frequently you can switch that of course.

Comment: Why map keys to keys instead of just mapping keys to objects? This isn't C++, where copying an object is wasteful; all you're doing is adding another reference.

Comment: because you may want to delete objects later what will you do  to synchronize the dicts?

Comment: And? Then you'll need to map _both_ types of keys to each other, as well as map at least one of them to the object. (Or, if the object already knows its keys, you don't need anything.)

Comment: you don't need to map both, you can probe the integer dict to see if it is alive always

Comment: So, if you're given an integer key to delete, how are you going to remove the string key from the string-to-int map? Or are you just going to leave them around forever?

Comment: you know there are lazy ways to do that. But I don't see how you would go about doing it with two dicts mapping the same object

Comment: As I said, if you need to delete objects given just one key, you need to map both kinds of keys to each other, or store the keys in the object. Just mapping one type of key to the other doesn't solve the problem. (And the "lazy way to do that" is presumably to wrap every lookup-by-string to get the key, see if the key is in the dict, and if not remove the string and propagate the error, right? That adds a whole lot of complexity, and I'm not sure what you gain for it.)